# Lucene Scoring: TermQuery w & w/o TermVectors

Tags: lucene, scoring

Does TermQuery:ExtractTerms result in a higher count when termvectors/positions/offsets are turned on? (assuming that there is more than 1 occurence of a match). Conversely, with the inverted file info turned off, does ExtractTerms always return 1 and only 1 term?

EDIT: How and where does turning on termvectors in the schema affect scoring?

Answer (score 1):

`TermQuery.ExtractTerms` extracts the terms in the *query*, not the result. So a search for "foo:bar" will always return exactly one term, regardless of what's in the index.

It sounds to me like you want to know about [highlighting](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html), not `Query.ExtractTerms`.

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, it sounds like you are asking: "how is *scoring* affected by term vectors?" The answer to that is: not at all. The term frequency, norm, etc. is calculated at index time, so it doesn't matter what you store.

The major exception is `PhraseQuery` with slop, which uses the term positions. A minor exception is that custom scoring classes can use whatever data they want, so not only term vectors but also payloads etc. can potentially affect the score.

If you're just doing `TermQuery`s though, what you store should have no effect.

Comment: Thx Xodarap. I don't want highlighting though. Thanks. I'm wondering mostly about the scoring effects, not performance or highlighting, of having termvectors on vs off.  I can't find the references for scoring based on position; what is commonly known in the literature as "1st occurrence" scoring; which would require the inv index to have positional information. As would proximity searches.

Comment: @willemIP: I have updated my answer to reflect what I think you're asking.

Comment: @Xodorap: So there is no 1st occurence scoring in by default? And there is no proximity either? Ok, but it does effect scoring. I have a reproducible case. Now I have to decide if this is an index time change or a query time; both indexing and querying affect scoring. Which one is causing the radical change in my relevance numbers from the simple inclusion/exclusion of termvectors on the search fields?

Comment: @willemIP: see [this](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) for how scoring works. It will depend on what type of query you are doing, so you might want to paste a code sample.

Comment: As I said, I turned termvector's off and then I turned them on. My tried/tested/and standardized (by/and in industry metrics) relevance tests show a marked difference. For all query types measured (>= 3 query types). More questions to follow I'm sure. I hope you will continue to engage where I make sense              btw: PCA and LDA approaches would frown on encoding to a byte with the notion that lossiness is ok in pursuit of memory footprint. Lucene should seek to make more precise its discrimination, not fuzzier.

Comment: precision allows for proper group memberships (yes plural); fuzziness obscures information